# how you make sure after setting Field Value that sourcing different values . i can execute rest of my code

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

i have a problem when set a entity field value that sourcing subsidiary and department and location
like 
'nlapiSetFieldValue('entity',x)'

i want execute code on list items which sourced based on item selection . i have tried setTimeOut()
but i look for a better solution

Comment: Please post the code you have written in your question, and any error message or other output you get.

Answer (score 0):

In theory all lists should be loaded when nlapi is ready, so this shouldn't be an issue. Though if you want to make sure, you can use setInterval to check every X seconds for values.